# SQL -- Excluding Tuples

Tags: sql, sql-server, filter, conditional-statements

I'm writing a query to select employee names from a database where the employees are married but have no children.

I have two different tables: Employee and Dependents

Employee has the following fields

```
fname, lname, ssn
```

And Dependents have the following fields

```
essn, dependents_name, relationship
```

Dependents.essn is a FK that references Employee.ssn

Some Employee.ssn have multiple tuples in Department, each with a different `relationship` status (spouse, son, daughter), describing the type of dependent that employee has.

I'm looking to write a query that selects those employees, based on the ssn -> essn relationship, that have the relationship `spouse` but not the relationships `son` or `daughter`.

So far, this is what I've tried:

```
select e.fname, d.relationship
from (employee e left outer join dependents d
on e.ssn = d.essn)
where d.relationship = 'spouse'
```

It returns the tuples of employees with the `spouse` value, but also with the `son` and `daughter` value.

How can I filter my tables to include only those employees with the `spouse` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `NOT EXISTS` clause

```
select e.fname, d.essn, d.relationship
from employee e 
join dependents d
on e.ssn = d.essn
and d.relationship = 'spouse'
and not exists ( select 1 from dependents d1
                 where d1.essn= e.ssn
                 and d1.relationship <> 'spouse'
)
```

Comment: What does `<>` mean in your nested statement? Also, `select 1`?

Comment: <> means not equal to , second one is corelated subquery , which will return 1 if there are other relationships for the same employee other than spouse , so not exists will then eliminate such row. here is sql fiddle http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d36cf/1

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm, but i used `select d1.essn` instead.

Comment: @mynorka, as sgeddes suggested, no need for lefjoin, just join should be fine in the select.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way with a common table expression and `count` with `partition`:

```
with cte as (
  select e.fname, 
    d.relationship,
    count(d.relationship) over (partition by e.ssn) cnt
  from employee e 
    join dependents d on e.ssn = d.essn
)
select fname, relationship
from cte
where cnt = 1 and relationship = 'spouse'
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78819/4)

---

BTW, no need for an `OUTER JOIN` -- your `WHERE` criteria negates it since you require a spouse to exist.

Comment: +1, works even if new relationship gets added to the schema and also count over partition is good for this case.

Comment: I'm just beginning to learn SQL, so I'm unfamiliar with `over` and `partition`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select e.fname
from employee e left outer join
     dependents d
     on e.ssn = d.essn
group by e.fname
having sum(case when d.relationship = 'spouse' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when d.relationship in ('son', 'daughter') then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```